# facebook connect logs user out of facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I use the php sdk for facebook connect. The Login as well as the logut works well, but the link facebook generated with: `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();` also logs the user out of facebook. How can i change this, so that only the user is logged out of my site but not of facebook?

All i found out is, that i must delete the facebook **session and cookie**. Is there a function for it in the sdk or how can i do this?

Thank you for any help

ruvenm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u click/access the values returned by getLogoutUrl , it will automatically logout the user session from facebook also.

If u dont want to logout from facebook , consider writing your own function for logout which destroys the sessions set by your application(I think u may hv atleast one session variable only related to the app)..

something like this

```
public function fnLogout()
{
  unset($_SESSION('uid')); 
  // add more session unset stmts for every session variable u may have set
  // write some code here to redirect to your app home page or something
}
```

Keep in notice that , whenever you try to login again ,you would have already logged in to facebook and you should try setting up your own session after checking the current user logged in!!

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); // will get the current fb user logged in
```

Comment: ah thank you. Dont know why i did not found it out myselve ;). Deleting the session will do the job. Is there a reason, why facebook handles the logout like this?

Comment: Consider you go to any site which has the option for login using your facebook credentials , once you login it will automatically login to facebook and if you are logging out from your application only, that leaves your facebook session live on your browser which may be used by other users using the same system/browser. That's why facebook automatically logsout from all at once.

Comment: Ah ok. But many sites also have their own logout script i see. I think it is better than to log the user out, isnt it?